# android: DateTimeView is a subclass of a TextView but not documented at all

Tags: android, datetime, view, textview

You could find it for example [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2c3e9e1/core/res/res/layout/notification_template_part_time.xml). It looks like Google uses it for a long time maybe but there is no documentation on it at developers at all. Seems like its a TextView but I can't say from which API lvl it is available since there is no documentation. But you could freely add it to your own layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    <DateTimeView
        android:id="@+id/txtTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

and no warning or exception will be thrown. Also it could be filled like:

```
View contentView = findViewById(R.id.contentView);
contentView.setLong(R.id.txtTime, "setTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

This will result in formatted date/time output. Its used to display date in notifications so you probably saw it numerous times already. Since I want to mimic standard nitification but with my own image out of R.drawable its enough of this kind of usage for me.
However I couldn't find any information using google and here on SO as well.
So what is it? A private API? Could I use it in my app actually?

Comment: The earliest that I found it go back to is version 2.2.1. Being that this is an undocumented API I would probably stay away from it

Comment: It's not a publicly visible class and is not guaranteed to exist, so you really shouldn't use it.

Comment: If I could add it to a layout and app compiles fine how could it be "not publicly visible"?